# How can I remove SID form URL in magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento2

I have made all setting from magneto backend that is "Session Validation Settings ->Use SID on Storefront   :no", clear all cache also. But still not able to remove SID from URL.

It's showing like this:

`https://www.exapmle.com/?SID=fpej05jr1fhoi3p083m72fj062`

How to remove the SID?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem.

Comment: yes #Devanshu, I got the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Ranjo Can ypu please update your answer here, so it may help others.

Comment: @RanjitShinde, First of all I disabled SID from Magento Backend and then added URL REWRITE RULE : 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.exapmle\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not selected store or storeview.
and follow bellow step.

Go to the Store > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings > Use SID on Storefront and set its value to No

Or

Isn't ?SID automatically added by PHP if PHP is configured to not store sessions on the server or the browser doesn't accept cookies?

Note:

The SID is a "session ID". Magento uses this to track a user's activity within the same Magento installation. Normally, Magento powers one website and one store from one installation (database).

Magento could power multiple websites with multiple stores from one installation though. The SID allows users to stay logged in while navigating across these websites/stores.

I think if you have the function enabled, the SID is sent when accessing catalog URLs so Magento can update the session with the user's location/state for the current website/store.

If you're not running a multi-website or multi-store environment, it's safe to disable the SID on the frontend.

Comment: Thanks Abhinav, yes, I did exactly the above settings but Still not working for me.